# Is there a short way to convert a variable name into a double pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

For example:

```
int x = 7          // x is variable name
int* p_x = &x      // p_x is a pointer to x
int** pp_x = &p_x  // pp_x is a double pointer to x.
```

Is there a quick way to go from `x` to `pp_x` without using a intermediate variable `p_x`?

EDIT:
Thanks to the comments below I realized that such a thing isn't really possible because without `p_x`, `pp_x` would be pointless (No pun intended) because it wouldn't be pointing to anything.

Comment: Well maybe you could use compound literal.

Comment: Is it C or C++? In C++ the answer is: "Don't use raw pointers"

Comment: if there's no intermediate `p_x`, what would `pp_x` point to ?

Comment: If it were possible what'd `*pp_x` would be? More importantly, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen My favourite: Herb Sutter's [GotW91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/): Raw pointers are fine for function parameters...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `pp_x` fills no purpose without `p_x`. So this is an "XY problem".

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Good point. My bad I guess.

Comment: @P.P. I have a function that receives a double pointer as a parameter.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen leaving out details is not always good. The correct chant is "Don't use raw **owning** pointers". Banning raw pointers completely is non-sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int** pp_x = &p_x  //pp_x is a double pointer to x.
```

It is a pointer to a pointer to x. So you must have `p_x` in order to have `pp_x` and you need to maintain `p_x` all the time you want access `x` via `pp_x`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. There are similar comments in the question comment thread.

Answer (score 6):

If you are targeting anything above C99 you could use compound literals - like following:

```
int **pp_x = (int *[1]){(int[1]){7}};
```

Comment: What would be the real world use of this construct?